# Ask Ubuntu Sessions at the Ubuntu Developer Summit

Tags: discussion, uds

Here are the sessions for this UDS that are AU related, they are all in the Community track:

- http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-p/track/community

More specifically:

- Integrating with Ask Ubuntu, Tuesday, 10am

  - [Notes](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-p/meeting/19718/community-askubuntu-integrate/)
  - [Video](http://www.youtube.com/user/ubuntudevelopers#p/search/1/2lgXqIiYDw4) of the session.
- Ask Ubuntu for Experts, Wednesday, 10am

  - [Notes](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-p/meeting/19717/community-askubuntu-experts/)
  - [Video](http://www.youtube.com/user/ubuntudevelopers#p/u/19/aHCIsRE_5HA) of the session.

For information on how to connect to IRC see this page on [Remote Participation](http://uds.ubuntu.com/participate/remote/)

Comment: I'll definitely participate remotely.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [an interview with Marco Ceppi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EM4Ko3Rsxb8&feature=feedu) that was recorded at UDS!

Comment: Awesome! Well done Marco. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to thank Marco and Jorge and congratulate them.

I think there was not a single session where I didn't hear something about Ask Ubuntu.

**Very well done guys!**